# TortoiseSvn: Post-Update Hook Script Error

Tags: svn, scripting, tortoisesvn, hook

I've tried numerous ways to get a post-update hook script working through TortoiseSVN, without much success.  Apparently a lot of people out there have this issue, but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Platform: Windows XP

Tortoise Version Information:
TortoiseSVN 1.6.7, Build 18415 - 32 Bit , 2010/01/22 17:55:06
Subversion 1.6.9, 
apr 1.3.8
apr-utils 1.3.9
neon 0.29.3
OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
zlib 1.2.3

I went to Settings -> Hook Scripts -> Add...

- Hook Type: Post-Update Hook
- WC Path: C:\proj1
- 1.Command Line to Execute: C:\FLASH.bat
- 2.Command Line to Execute: "C:\FLASH.bat"
- 3.Command Line to Execute: cmd /c "C:\FLASH.bat"

My FLASH.bat file only contains:
exit 0

Those are the three different things I tried -- none worked.  Every time I try an update, I get the following error message: "the hook script returned an error"

Comment: Are you sure the hook script didn't return an error?! In other words, was the script called correctly by Tortoise, but then failed itself?

Comment: The script contains "exit 0" that's it.  I tried "exit 1" as well, just in case Tortoise thinks 0 is an error.  Neither worked.  I also tried "exit /b 0" and I tried "echo > test.txt" without the "exit" line.  None of these worked.

Comment: For me, `D:\temp\postcommit.bat` as command line works, as long as I write `exit 0`. I get only an error if I write `exit 1` (TortoiseSVN 1.6.12)

Comment: Are you trying [to commit to switched paths](https://superuser.com/q/1229204)?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with TortoiseSVN 1.8.11 always giving "the hook script returned an error", "the system cannot find the file specified". The problem was that the local pre-commit hook (`tsvn:precommithook`) needs to specify the batch file with an **absolute** path (1.8 doesn't specify a WC Path; sometimes it is called from the root of the project, other times somewhere deeper), with each **backslash \ replaced by slash /**.

Of the other options, if you want to "Wait for the script to finish" and not "Hide the script while running", note that the script runs with output redirected somewhere else. If you want to see output from a command in the script, you'll need to redirect that command's output to CON, e.g.

```
pause >>CON
```